# Creating a new user in ADAL TokenValidated results in duplicates

Tags: sql-server, rest, azure, asp.net-core, adal

I have a multi-tenant REST app. When a new user first tries to access my application ( and assuming their admin has already granted the app permission for their directory ) I create a user row in my User table and store their name/email and other fields. I perform this in the TokenValidated event of JwtBearerEvents.

Unfortunately, I'm ending up with multiple users rows attempting to be inserted because of simultaneous (parallel request) hitting my web API. I do a simple SQL query for the User by ObjectId, and then create if necessary. This isn't threadsafe. I tried wrapping it in a SQL transaction, but the select isn't blocking and I'm not sure EF Core lets me perform the kind of locking I'd need to block other selects from completing.

I'm basing my code off the [TailSpin PnP](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/guidance-multitenant-identity-signup/) and they perform the same logic here as well. My guess is their site logic is forcing a single call the the WEB API first as part of the sign-in/login process, where the new user is created if they don't exist. In my flow, the REST API is hit right off the bat with multiple HTTP GET's and I just have to validate the bearer token in the headers and let ADAL cache it.

Aside from changing my client logic, and forcing the first call to API to  be a single HTTP GET, how else can I make this work in a REST world? I can't use SESSION logic to block other calls in the same session. I'm not sure how I can perform a lock across the whole server ( Which works only if there's one server ). I could use the DB layer to hold a write lock, but that seems dirty. Maybe there's a better place to put the Create new user logic? Is there some other way for me to safely perform a one time atomic operation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the description, it seems you were create the user record(sign-up) when the users call the REST API and after the token is validated.

To fix the duplicates records issue, one possible way is that separate the sign-up progress from token validation as same the code sample TailSpin PnP. For example, we can custom the token handler to verify whether the users is sign-up and provide the UI for the users sign-up.

Another way is that, you can insert the users sequentially by using the lock. For example, here is the code for your reference:

```
private Task tokenValidated(TokenValidatedContext context)
{
    lock (obj)
    {
        //query db and insert users here
    }
    return Task.Delay(0);

}
```

Comment: I considered using a lock, but was unsure what to lock on. Either way it protects me only if were running on a single server. What would you use as the lock object?

Comment: I use a object which created in the `Startup` class which should work for the single instance app. An other easy way to prevent to insert duplicated records, you may consider set the proper primary key for the **User** table. For example, you may set the **ObjectId** as the primary key.

Comment: The missing key in the DB was a deployment issue that has sense been fixed. I ended up writing the code to handle an insert exception and switch from "Create" to "Get" mode in that case, so that autoscale can still work ( multiple web service instances ). Still feels wrong to me, but oh well for now.